# Trying to pass arguments to wp-cli in a bash script

Tags: wordpress, bash, cron, wp-cli

I'm using a wp-cli tool in order to optimize images:

`$ wp image-optimize batch --limit=20`

I've installed wpcli using composer so it's in an unusual location, but is in my `$PATH`:
`/home/user/.config/composer/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp`

This works great. I'd like to run this command nightly. I've tried two different approaches to this. First, I tried running the command as a cronjob (set every minute for testing):

`$ crontab -e`

`* * * * * cd /path/to/example.com && wp image-optimize batch --limit=20`

I got no response. I wondered if the problem had something to do with passing arguments in a cronjob. So, I created a bash script `nightly-image-optimize` (also in path) hoping that this might get around it:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "begin" >> /home/user/cronlog.log

cd /path/to/example.com

sh /home/user/.config/composer/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp image-optimize batch --limit=2

echo "end" >> /home/user/cronlog.log
```

I then modified the cronjob to execute this file every minute as my username since cron runs as root:
`* * * * * username /usr/local/bin/nightly-image-optimize`

I know the cronjob is running because my cronlog.log file is created and is populated every minute with the echo begin and end statements above.

While in context this is a wp-cli problem, I don't believe that the issue has anything to do with wp-cli. I think I'm misunderstanding how to essentially 'tell' bash to run a process as if I had manually entered it in (maybe something to do with the interactivity of wp-cli?).

Any ideas?

Note:
I'm on AWS running Ubuntu 18.04.3 as a non-root user with sudo privileges

Comment: Hi, perhaps redirect output from the entire command to a log (append `>> /home/user/log.txt 2>&1` to the cron command) You could also add some logging to the optimize command with `optimizationChain->useLogger` https://github.com/TypistTech/image-optimize-command/blob/27dfd74f1fb87bffe7cbf0d9bbed7f424b8e455f/README.md

Comment: What is the output if you run the call in a bash terminal : sh /home/user/.config/composer/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp image-optimize batch --limit=2 Does it work then?

Comment: @Madman - When I run:

 `cd /var/www/standardrestaurant.com/ && sh /home/username/.config/composer/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp image-optimize batch --limit=2`

it works

Comment: @IronMan - I adjusted the script as follows:

Comment: @IronMan - I adjusted the script as follows:
`sh /home/username/.config/composer/vendor/wp-cli/wp-cli/bin/wp image-optimize batch --limit=2 >> /home/skyler/scriptlog.log 2>&1`

After this change, scriptlog.log is created, but is empty

Comment: Okay, I have no idea why, but when I came in this morning, it worked. The only change I made was to add some logging as suggested by @IronMan. I can only assume I had a typo in there somewhere that was causing me problems